# SQL: Select Distinct from specific column

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct, ms-access-2013

Context:
I am working on developing an Access 2013 database for a work project.  It access some back-end systems, and brings them together for reporting.  One of those systems contains employee data.  I'm writing an SQL query statement to pull a list of active employees from a certain department.  However, When I run it I noticed that some employees are listed twice in the database.  I don't have access to edit the back-end data!  So I must remove the duplicates from my side. 
 When I try selecting distinct values it doesn't count because "some" of the info I pull in other columns is different (like tel #).

Question:
How can I eliminate duplicate values from a query based on info in only one column, instead of the whole table?  Is there a way to do this with DISTINCT, or another option?

Sort of like how when you remove duplicates from excel you can specify which columns to consider

Sincerely,
Kris

Comment: We would need to see your table structure and the query you have now.  You could select distinct records for that one column that is unique and then select some ID from the table, then use an outer query to select all fields from that table has the ID (from the sub select) in it.  This may/may not work depending on your structure and how your data is laid out, if you can post that we can get better answer

Comment: You could use a GROUP BY/Aggregation: `SELECT employee_name, employee_id, max(telephone), max(email_addr) FROM table GROUP BY employee_name, employee_id;` If you don't want telephone or other non-distinct columns in your output, then you could just select the stuff you want and stick all of those columns in your GROUP BY.

Comment: A question regarding SQL queries, having 15 lines of text, without any piece of code, table structure and data, is NOT a good question. Please edit your question and add all this.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways of doing this.

1. You can use distinct.
2. You can use group by on particular column. It will make sure that column values will be unique in result.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume we have a table called Department, and it has 4 columns as in
DptName, DptAddress, DptCode, DptTel . now we want to delete all records which are identical for first 3 and are only different on DptTel.

(you can accommodate this to your actual table and equality logic)

here's a query to achieve so

```
;with cte as (
    select DptName, count(DptName) as cnt
    from Department
    group by DptName, DptAddress, DptCode
    having count(DptName) > 1
)
, cte2 as (
select top 1 * from Department
where exists (
    select *
    from cte
    where cte.DptName = Department.DptName
)

union

select * from Department
where not exists (
    select *
    from cte
    where cte.DptName = Department.DptName
)
)

delete from Department
where not exists (
    select *
    from cte2
    where cte2.DptTel = Department.DptTel
)
```

it's fully tested and can be utilized, you only have to fill in the list of columns and specify the differences on the final select.

Voila !!

Comment: Does the OP want to "delete" data from the query or from the base tables? The query doesn't make this clear. It is possible he just wants to filter the queried data, rather than deleting from the base tables.

Comment: this is for if he wants to delete from the table. but for filtering alone, it can be reduced to only results from cte2. filtering scenario is even more simple. i thought deleting is the intention.